# How to set ACL to public-read on AWS-SDK-PHP v3.2 using transfer manager

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

ok, my first SO question, be nice.

I am having problems finding the answer to this question. yes ive tried
the options for the transfer constructor don't mention any ACL options.
my searches on google come up either blank or for version 2.x
 this is my code

```
$options[] = [
'DEBUG' => true,
];
// Where the files will be transferred to
$dest = 's3://newbucket/'.$UUID;
// Create a transfer object.
$manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($s3, $path, $dest, $options );
// Perform the transfer synchronously.
$manager->transfer();
$promise = $manager->promise();
$promise->then(function () {
    echo 'Done!';
});
```

everything uploads ok but the files are not public-read
where/how do i set Public-read on the files uploaded in VERSION 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `'before'` closure to the array of options you're passing to the transfer manager that could handle assigning permissions. Try replacing your manager instantiation code with this:

```
$manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($s3, $path, $dest, [
    'before' => function (\Aws\CommandInterface $command) {
        if (in_array($command->getName(), ['PutObject', 'CreateMultipartUpload'])) {
            $command['ACL'] = 'public-read';
        }
    },
]);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Where can I read more about before function. I wanna only make file with .ts extension public.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is set the permissions on the Bucket in the console. under permissions of the bucket you want to set. click 'edit bucket policy'

The other peice of info you will need is how to create the JSON file that you paste in. http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html  if you get an error from AWS's tool just reformat it based on what you see in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

I hope that helps others